# How to get the device token at the time of registration in react native

Tags: android, react-native, devicetoken

How do i get the device token when a user is registered in an app.The purpose is that i want to send push notification using fcm. Can anybody please help ?

Comment: check this https://github.com/SeuJota/react-native-device-token

Comment: Sorry.. so how do i retrieve this generated token?I mean do i need to write any extra code in native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I did kinda the same thing I went with this lib: https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm

Which I think works great btw.

When the user clicks on the register button or whatever, I do:

```
FCM.getFCMToken().then(token => {
    //Send register request
});
```

The token can change as well, so whenever the app is started I compare the existing key from AsyncStorage and if it has changed I'll use the same procedure to update the key backend.

Hope this helps, good luck.